# Program works when I input the number but when I backspace it to enter another number it shows error

Tags: vb.net

My program works when I input the number but when I backspace it to enter another number it shows an error.

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
        Dim calculate = 100
        Label1.Text = "The calculation is " & (TextBox1.Text * calculate)
    End Sub

End Class
```

[image: form picture]

Comment: Turn Option Strict On. Multiplying a string can cause you trouble.

Comment: What is the actual text of the error message?

Answer (score 0):

Before your calculation you have to check that `TextBox1.Text <> ""`.

```
If TextBox1.Text <> "" Then
    Label1.Text = "The calculation is " & (TextBox1.Text * 100)
Else
    Label1.Text = "no value"
End If
```

Comment: @tezzo It would be good if you used [`Option Strict On`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29985039/1115360) when writing answers as it leads to code which works better and more reliably.

Comment: @SandeshSharma Please accept the answer by clicking the check mark (tick mark) to the left of the answer.